# Get current URL for pagination

Tags: php

I have a paging function for multiple pages.

Instead of setting the URL in the function. e.g `mypaginatefunction($current_page_number, 'forum/?action=showthread&id=$threadid, $per_page` I just wanna PHP to figure it out.

Currently I'm using:

```
$link = strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'?').'?'.http_build_query($_GET);
<a href=\"$link&page=$page_number\">$page_number</a>
```

But that don't work so good. It will keep the previous $_GET too

For example lets say I'm on `http://xxx/forum/?action=showthread&id=181`

And I press on page 2 `http://xxx/forum/?action=showthread&id=181&page=2`

but then if I press page 3 it becomes: `http://mysite/forum/?action=showthread&id=181&page=2&page=3`

I'd only want `&page=3`

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

```
$queryParams = $_GET;
$queryParams['page'] = $page_number;
$link = strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'?').'?'.http_build_query($queryParams);
```

Comment: should not be possible to get multiple &page= instances in your link, if you build it like this. Can i see your current code, and result?

Answer (score 0):

```
$link = strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'?').'?page='.$_GET['page']);
```

If you want the `action` part you can do it with:

```
$link = strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'?').'?action=showthread&page='.$_GET['page']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not the best, but for a temporary solution you can use this:

```
$url = 'http://xxx/forum/?action=showthread&id=181&page=2';
$new_url = preg_replace('/page=[\d+]/', 'page=3', $url);
```